# Why when I click submit is it not hitting the action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor-2

I have made a completely fresh MVC5 homepage and followed this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Instead of just adding 2 fields (HomeTown, BirthDate) i have added a lot of fields.

This is what i have modified in IdentityModel:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? GenderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int? Phone { get; set; }
    public string Homepage { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int? ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int? CountryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public bool Verified { get; set; }
}
```

This is what i have modified in AccountViewModels:

```
 public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Gender")]
    [Required]
    public int? GenderId { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("CheckEmail", "Account", ErrorMessage = "Email is already registered")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm email")]
    [Compare("Email", ErrorMessage = "The email and confirmation email do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }
}
```

This is my register view:

```
@model MembershipTutorial.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<h4>Create a new account.</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GenderId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GenderId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.GenderId, String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenderId)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Birthday, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthday)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birthday)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="left-inner-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmEmail, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ConfirmEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail)
    </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
    </div>
</div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
}
```

If i just click the submit button without entering anything it shows validation on everything. As i fill in the different fields the validation error messages goes away (as they should), but then when i hit submit. NOTHING HAPPENS. i have debugged it and set breakpoint at the start of:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
```

but that never gets called. if i change the code back to 100% default then it gets called again. What did i mess up here? Wish it would just throw an exception in my face so i could see where the problem was.

Comment: Did you wire up the System.Web.Mvc.Remote("CheckEmail", "Account"?

Comment: I had an issue with mvc4 and bootstrap2. Basically client validation was failing but because of the DOM structure the error was not being shown. And there for the control method was not being fired.

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem was that i had copied the fields from a previous project, but forgot to implement that remote method. Make an answer and i will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you wire up the System.Web.Mvc.Remote("CheckEmail", "Account"?